# how to apply a css class to a span defined in jQueryMobile collapsible div . I would like to toggle a css class when it is clicked on span

Tags: jquery

I would like to apply a css class defined as underlined to a span that generates a click so it should toggle. I have tried but can't seem to figure out why it is not doing. I am using simple jQuery and JQuery Mobile fame work.

Your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Previus

```
     <h3>Verbal Reasoning / Opposites and Similar to</h3>
```

Next

```
</div>
<div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
     <h4>Under line the words which are most opposite in meaning.</h4>

    <div data-role="collapsible-set">
        <div data-role="collapsible" data-inset="false">
             <h2>1.1</h2>

            <div class="ui-grid-d">
                <div class="ui-block-a"><span class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">ability</span>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-b"><span class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">able</span>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-c"><span class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">inability</span>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-d"><span class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">capable</span>

                </div>
                <div class="ui-block-e"><span class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow">hidden</span>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



css
.underlined{
    text-decoration:underline;
}

jQuery
$("span").on('click'),function(){
   $("span").toggleClass('underlined'); 

});
```

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone mentioned, there is an error in your click handler; the correct way to write it is:

```
$(".word").on('click',function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('underlined'); 
});
```

In addition, the text-decoration in .underlined is not taken into account because something else takes precedence over it. Declare .underline as:

```
.underlined{
    text-decoration:underline !important;
}
```

See fiddle here:  http://jsfiddle.net/robbyn/h6perr8c/

Answer (score 0):

Small code error:

```
$("span").on('click'),function(){
   $("span").toggleClass('underlined'); 
});
```

Remove the bracket after `'click'`:

```
$("span").on('click',function(){
   $("span").toggleClass('underlined'); 
});
```

**EDIT:**

If I were to rewrite your function, I would do like this:

```
$("span").click(function(){
   $(this).toggleClass('underlined'); 
});
```

use `$(this)` as it will refer to clicked element, not ALL span elements